# How to scan Samsung Scanner / Printer with Powershell

Tags: powershell, wia, image-scanner

I am attempting to us a Powershell script to find a scanner on my network. Scan a document and save the file to a location.

=================================================================

When I use a USB connected Epson scanner, the script below works. If I use our Network Multifunction Scanner Samsung SCX-472x, it does not recognize the scanner in the Device Manager.

The driver for the Samsung is TWAIN / WIA as is the Epson.

=============================================================

```
$deviceManager = new-object -ComObject WIA.DeviceManager
$device = $deviceManager.DeviceInfos.Item(1).Connect() 

$wiaFormatPNG = "{B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}"

foreach ($item in $device.Items) 
{ 

    $image = $item.Transfer($wiaFormatPNG) 
} 

if($image.FormatID -ne $wiaFormatPNG)
{

   $imageProcess = new-object -ComObject WIA.ImageProcess
```

`$imageProcess.Filters.Add($imageProcess.FilterInfos.Item("Convert").FilterID)`

```
   $imageProcess.Filters.Item(1).Properties.Item("FormatID").Value = 
   $wiaFormatPNG
   $image = $imageProcess.Apply($image)
}

$image.SaveFile("C:/Scans/Scan.png")
```

=========================================================

I need Powershell to scan from a Samsung Network Scanner and save the file to a specified location.

Comment: Is this your full code? Which line actually initiates the scanning?

Comment: `$deviceManager = new-object -ComObject WIA.DeviceManager`
`$device = $deviceManager.DeviceInfos.Item(1).Connect()`